# Linq return JSON

Tags: asp.net, json, linq

I write this code:

```
SqlConnection Conn = new SqlConnection(connStr);
DataClasses1DataContext behzad = new DataClasses1DataContext(Conn);

var qy = (from p in behzad.Resturants
          select new
          {
              p.id,
              .Name
          }).Skip(2).Take(1);

JavaScriptSerializer jss = new JavaScriptSerializer();
Label1.Text = jss.Serialize(qy);

string json = jss.Serialize(qy);

return json;
```

Can I use this method from client to access data on server, linq to json?

Comment: You mean send data from client to server?

Comment: No my friends,means client get data from server

Comment: Yes you can, if that's the only thing you wonder about.

Comment: how can i ,please explain or send me tutorial link

Comment: Are you writing a stand alone application or does this have a webpage front end?

Comment: yes i have a webpage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you are looking for [OData](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/odata-support-in-aspnet-web-api), a protocol that exposes a data model through REST as XML and Json. It's very easy to expose an Entity Framework model as an OData service using ASP.NET Web API 2 as Visual Studio includes OData controller templates. You can find a step-by-step tutorial at [Creating an OData Endpoint](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/odata-support-in-aspnet-web-api/creating-an-odata-endpoint).

Using Entity Framework, an OData controller can be as simple as that:

```
public class AirlinesController : EntitySetController<Airline,int>
{
  private AirlineContext db = new AirlineContext();
  public override IQueryable<Airline> Get()
  {
    return db.Airlines;
  }
}
```

which you can call from Javascript with a URL like:

```
http://localhost:1702/oairlinedata/Airlines?$filter=startswith(Name,'Vermont')
```

You can check [Julie Lerman's MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn201742.aspx) for more details, or you can check ASP.NET's section on [OData support](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/odata-support-in-aspnet-web-api)

Clients call an OData service either by constructing a URL with the appropriate filter,select parameters or by using a library to construct it. The [.NET client](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/odata-support-in-aspnet-web-api/calling-an-odata-service-from-a-net-client) allows you to use LINQ (LINQ is only available in .NET after all).

In Javascript, you can simply [make an AJAX call with the appropriate parameters](http://codesmartinc.com/2011/01/31/leveraging-odata-end-points-in-json-format-with-jquery/) and read the Json object, or you can use a library like [datajs](http://datajs.codeplex.com/)